# Recursive Binary search algorithm - Python

Tags: python

there are a lot of ways to write Binary search algorithm in recursion 
but they all return True if the value was found in the list or False otherwise.
is there any possible way to write Binary search algorithm in recursion so that
afterwards I'll get the **index** of the founded value? more important - will it still
be in log(n)? I'm not looking for **built-in function!**

Here is my code, so far:

```
def bin_search(val,L): 
    if len(L) == 1:
      if L[0] == val:
        return True
      else:
        return False
    else:
        hi = len(L)
    lo = 0
    mid = (hi + lo)//2
    if val == L[mid]:
        return True
    elif val > L[mid]:
        bin_search(val,L[mid + 1:])
    elif val < L[mid]:
        bin_search(val,L[:mid + 1])
```

Comment: There is already an implementation [bisect.bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) in Python's standard library. Search the code base to see how it works

Comment: Sure. You can either reconstruct the indices on the way out, or pass down a list and a pair of indices instead of a slice. Show us your code and we can show you how to adapt it.

Comment: @Abhijit: Well, [`bisect`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7c4f0c3dedaf/Lib/bisect.py) doesn't actually return the indices, just use them. And it's not recursive, it's a loop. So it proves that it's possible, but doesn't directly show you how to do it.

Comment: Abhijit, I'm not looking for built-in function

Comment: @user3045065: The built-in and stdlib functions are useful because they all come with [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/). Sure, in CPython some are implemented in C rather than Python… but in that case, you can always look at the [PyPy source](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src) instead.

Comment: @user3045065 StackOverflow is not a "do-my-coding-for-me" place. You need to show your effort and prove that you have at the very least attempted to solve your problem. *Then* (and only then) you can ask questions about ***specific*** problems that you are facing. Please [read this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: What information do you have about the found position when you make the  recursive call?  How can you use that when you return?

Comment: Your implementation raises a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` in half the cases, and return `None` in most other cases. You have to give us _working_ code, not just something sort of similar to working code

Comment: user3045065 I uploaded my code. I forgot to do so.

Comment: abarnert, of course. That why I asked this question.

Comment: @user3045065: I don't know which comment you're answering "of course" to. If it's the one about the built-in and stdlib functions coming with source code for you to read, how is that a reason to ask the question? If it's the one about your implementation not working as you claim, then, assuming you actually don't know how to write a binary search that returns True/False in the first place rather than just being lazy, you're asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing function has at least two major problems: It doesn't `return` the value from the recursive calls, meaning that it usually ends up returning `None` if it finishes; it uses the wrong bounds to slice the list, meaning half the time it ends up with infinite recursion.

If you fix those, then all you have to do is return the index instead of True, and something else (e.g., -1, or raise an exception) instead of False. That means the recursive calls will get the index into the slice instead of the whole list, but they know the offset and can adjust it.

So, first:

```
if len(L) == 1:
    if L[0] == val:
        # return True
        return 0
    else:
        # return False
        raise ValueError('not found')
else:
    hi = len(L)
    lo = 0
    mid = (hi + lo)//2
    if val == L[mid]:
        # return True
        return mid
    elif val > L[mid]:
        # return bin_search(val,L[mid + 1:])
        return mid + 1 + bin_search(val,L[mid + 1:])
    elif val < L[mid]:
        # no change here, because the offset is 0
        return bin_search(val,L[:mid])
```

And that's it. It should be obvious that this is doing the exact same sequence of recursive calls, and the only extra work is adding `mid + 1` in just under half the cases, so it still has the same complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
def binaryIndex(L, x, offset=0):
    if not L:
        return -1  # item does not exist in the list
    elif L[len(L)//2] == x:
        return offset + len(L)//2
    elif L[len(L)//2] > x:
        return binaryIndex(L[:len(L)//2], x, offset)
    else:
        return binaryIndex(L[(len(L)//2)+1:], x, offset+(len(L)//2)+1)
```

Output:

```
>>> binaryIndex([0,1,2,3,4], 0)
0
>>> binaryIndex([0,1,2,3,4], 1)
1
>>> binaryIndex([0,1,2,3,4], 2)
2
>>> binaryIndex([0,1,2,3,4], 3)
3
>>> binaryIndex([0,1,2,3,4], 4)
4
>>> binaryIndex([0,1,2,3,4], 5)
-1
```

And yes, this is still O(log(n))